# Selecting only displayed features using select by rectangle tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, select

I have a shapefile with many features, only some of which are displayed. I'm using the "Select Features by Rectangle" tool (the one where you click and drag a box over the features you want to select). I want to only select visible features within the rectangle, however the tool also selects features which are not displayed. Does anyone know how to avoid this?

I'm using ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: what do you mean by "not displayed". Is it a transparent symbology or a query ?

Comment: What happens if a feature cannot be seen because it is totally hidden by another feature from the same layer - should it be selected?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I have a custom tool that also selects features not visible in the map and I would like to know of a way to only select "individual features" that are visible, not just based on the visibility of the layer - but the visibility of the individual feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a definition query (properties/definition query tab) as opposed to removing values from the symbology, you will only be able to select visible features.

Comment: I need to make the selection manually. There's really no way to make the process automated.

Comment: it is all a manual process, you would just have to use the same symbology criteria you have already applied, but enter it as a definition query instead, and that will prevent unwanted features from being included, and no features you want to avoid will be selectable or visible.

Answer (score 2):

In your table to contents, Right click on the layer you are trying to do the selection from. Then go to "Selection" and choose "make this the only selectable layer". That is, if your selection is all contained within one layer.

Comment: The selection is all contained within one layer. The problem is that I only want to select features that are displayed. I've used symbology by category to display the features I'm interested in (by turning off "all other values").I want to select from those displayed features.

Comment: @Scott Can you use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with this and any other clarifications that you make, please?